# "try" not passing after "def"

Tags: python, python-2.7, try-except

I'm just trying Python, and really like it! But I get stucked with try/except.

I have a code that checks raw_input for being integer, but i'd like to make it function, and it doesn't want to be it :)

here the code, I have this:

```
number_of_iterations = raw_input("What is your favorite number?")
try:
    int(number_of_iterations)
    is_number = True
except:
    is_number = False

while not is_number:
    print "Please put a number!"
    number_of_iterations = raw_input("What is your favorite number?")
    try:
        int(number_of_iterations)
        is_number = True
    except:
        is_number = False
```

I don't want to repeat myself here& So I think smth about to make function:

```
def check_input(input_number):
    try:
        int(input_number)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

But it make an error if input a string, saying that int can't be used for strings. Looks like it does not see 'try' keyword.
Can smone explain why it happens and how to prevent it in future?

Comment: What is the error traceback? How are you calling `check_input`?

Comment: Don't use `except` without error class definition. This will mean handling `KeyboardInterrupt` or such. Use `except ValueError` or at least `Exception`. Take a look at pythons [built in exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html).

Comment: In the except cause, raise and see the traceback

Comment: Personally, I'd put `return True` in an `else` block of the `try/except`.  It's bad to pile functionality in to a `try` block when you are using it like an `if` like you are here.  Any of the other statements following the statement you are actually trying to handle errors from will also be caught by the `except`, which can lead to annoying bugs.  `try` what you are `try`ing, `else` what the `try` is `if`ing.

Comment: I think OP has left us. :)

Comment: I'd say you are doing `int(number_of_iterations)` somewhere outside a try/except block

Comment: @Vyktor It's magic :) and it is work. I'll be more careful with exceptions now. It is strange it passed if it is not in function. Thanks for help.

Comment: @sr2222 but as I understand, I can not use if/else statement here, raw_input always return the string, even if you type a number. so if statement will always return false.

Comment: I don't literally mean `if`, but you are using a `try/except` block to basically function like an `if` statement.  `if not raised_exception(something()): do_stuff()`.  Putting the conditional behavior in the `try` block is like calling `do_stuff()` from within `something()` instead of as a result of what `something()` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it avoids repeating yourself without needing a `def`

```
while True:
    try:
        number_of_iterations = int(raw_input("What is your favorite integer?"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Please put an integer!"
```

**EDIT**:  Per the suggestions of the commenters, I have added `break` to the `try` portion of the block to eliminate the `else` (the original remains as a reference below).  Also, I changed "number" to "integer" because "3.14" would be invalid in the above code.

This was my original suggestion.  The above is fewer lines (some may call this cleaner), but I prefer the below because to me the intent is clearer.

```
while True:
    try:
        number_of_iterations = int(raw_input("What is your favorite integer?"))
    except ValueError:
        print "Please put an integer!"
    else:
        break
```

Comment: very elegant, thanks for your answer. Don't know, we can use _else_ here.. going to docs.

Comment: Or simply `while True:` `try:` `number_of_iterations = ...` `break` `except ValueError:` `print "Please put a number!"`

Comment: Perhaps you could avoid the `else` statement and include `break` in the `try` statement, underneath `number_of_iterations`. Might be a little cleaner

Answer (score 1):

If you want it as a function, decide two things:

- What is it going to need to work, and
- What it's going to need to spit back out.

Your use case is that you need some sort of int back, and if it bombs out for whatever reason, it's defined as not a number.

Let's create a tuple as our return value, so we can return a number of some kind and a boolean for "if it is a number".

```
def check_input(number):
    try:
        return (int(number), True)
    except ValueError:
        return (-999999, False) # Care more about boolean here
```

We can then use that return value in our `while` loop like so.  Note that I explicitly set the loop condition to `False`, so we enter in at least once.

```
is_number = False
num = -999999 # Define out of scope of loop so it can be used

while not is_number:
    print "Please put a number!"
    num, is_number = check_input(raw_input("What is your favorite number?"))
```

The line `num, is_number` is a result of [tuple packing](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).  Since we're returning a tuple from our method, we can set two distinct variables to the results of that tuple.

Comment: thats good, but do I understand clearly, that it **always** will ask us to "put a number" at first time?

And I have one question.. if it is not hard for you to explain, why you use here such a contruction
`return (int(number), True)`
and
`return (-999999, False)` ?
First I can understand, but second.. what is "-999999"? Is it chaining with bitwise '~' somehow?

Comment: No, it's a dummy value.  Admittedly you care less about the integer when it's "not a number" than you would if it was.  And yes, given a linear flow through the program, if `is_number` is `False`, you will always loop.